# Android Studio showing this error :Retrofit2 Android HTTP method annotation is required (e.g., @GET, @POST, etc.)

Tags: java, android, api, kotlin, retrofit

It keeps showing me this error in Android Studio, I am using retrofit 2, trying to get data from Yelp API and it keeps showing me this msg

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sf.alomari.yelp/sf.alomari.view.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HTTP method annotation is required (e.g., @GET, @POST, etc.).
for method StoresApi.searchStores

And this is the SearchStores Method

```
import io.reactivex.Single
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Header
import retrofit2.http.Query

interface StoresApi {

    @GET("businesses/search")
    fun getStore(): Single<List<Stores>>
  fun searchStores(
      @Header("Authorization")authHeader:String,
      @Query("term")searchTerm:String,
      @Query("location")location:String): Call<List<Stores>>



}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That's simply because you haven't annotated your `searchStores` function. There is this `fun getStore(): Single<List<Stores>>` function in between the GET annotation and `searchStore` function and looking at the endpoint, probably the GET annotation is for the `searchStore` function. You need to annotate each function separately.

I guess it should look like this:

```kotlin
interface StoresApi {

    @GET("your-endpoint")
    fun getStore(): Single<List<Stores>>

    @GET("businesses/search")
    fun searchStores(
      @Header("Authorization") authHeader: String,
      @Query("term") searchTerm: String,
      @Query("location") location: String
    ): Call<List<Stores>>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You have missed the annotation for the second function,. Every function needs its own annotation.

```
@GET("businesses/search")    
fun searchStores(
  @Header("Authorization") authHeader: String,
  @Query("term") searchTerm: String,
  @Query("location") location: String
): Call<List<Stores>>
```